# how to get the address of an asm function in c

Tags: c, gnu-assembler

I have an asm file (I'm using gas) and a c file. My asm file contains a function, something like this

```
.global myfunc
.type myfunc, @function

myfunc:
   pusha
   .
   .
   .
```

now I want to get the address of the label myfunc from my c file, so I've wrote

```
extern uintptr_t _myfunc asm("myfunc");
```

my program links without problems, but when I execute my program the variable _myfunc doesn't contain the right address.

**Edit 1**

maybe it's useful to know that this piece of code is part of a bare-metal program

**Edit 2**

using a function prototype solved the problem

```
void function() asm("myfunc");

uintptr_t _myfunc = (uintptr_t)&myfunc;
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't contain the right address?

Comment: I've examined the memory with gdb using the command x/i.

Comment: If you call this function from the C code, will it execute correctly?

Comment: hm are you sure this isn't address space randomization at work?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm using it in a bare-metal program

Comment: good point :) you might want to add this piece of information to your original question as an edit.

Comment: Why not just simply create a prototype, and use it like any other function which decays naturally to a pointer to the function? And if you're uncertain then use the address-of operator like `&myfunc`. Then let the linker resolve the address.

Comment: I still don't understand what are you comparing to what. How do you get the "correct" address, and how do you see the "incorrect" one? Can you add the steps to the question body?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thx, that solved the problem

Comment: One of you should add an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to declare your asm function in C using the same symbol you use in the `.global` declaration:

```
extern void myfunc(void);
```

The symbols are resolved by the linker. As long as the object file created from your asm file exports the symbol `myfunc`, the object file from your C source may contain an undefined reference to it.

Depending on the particular ABI or object file format (a.out versus ELF), you may need to use `_myfunc` instead of `myfunc` in the `extern` declaration.